# Random numbering and spacing of sub-figures in pdf output

Tags: floats, formatting, subfloats

The numbering of the sub-figures in my pdf output is kind of random, but in the editor the numbering is as it should be.

Where the sub-figures are correctly numbered from (a) to (d), but when exported to pdf, this is what i get:

[image]

I would also like to ask why is the horizontal spacing in the first row of figures different? The settings for each line are the same yet the first row does not follow.

I dont know how to fix this. Here is a `LaTeX` code of the figure:

```
%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\subfloat[]{\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_0_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_1_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_2_ground_truth}}}

\subfloat[]{\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_0_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_1_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_2_ground_truth}}}

\subfloat[]{\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_0_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_1_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_2_ground_truth}}}

\subfloat[]{\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_0_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_1_ground_truth}}\enskip{}\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.28\paperwidth]{volume_4_2_ground_truth}}}

\caption{Comparison}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's a good idea to nest `\subfloat`s...

Comment: Understood. Can you please suggest how I would get the required arrangement of my figure?

Comment: I am no specialist in floats (since they never do what I want them to do). You can either wait for an answer that solves your problem or you can have a look at the `tcolorbox` package adding your subcaptions manually. Option 1 might be the better one though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly that you need only four captions (from (a) to (d), one per row), you may simply remove the nested `\subfloat`:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}%
}

\subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}%
}

\subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}%
}

\subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}\enskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\paperwidth]{example-image}%
}

\caption{Comparison}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\includegraphics` command inside minipages of your desired width.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{volume_4_0_ground_truth}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{volume_4_1_ground_truth}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{volume_4_2_ground_truth}
\end{minipage}\vspace{15pt}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{volume_4_0_ground_truth}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{volume_4_1_ground_truth}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{volume_4_2_ground_truth}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Comparison}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

A caption can be included if you wish by using the command: `\captionof{subfigure}{Caption (a)}`